# How do I soup this without it doing nothing?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm tampering around with BS4 and web scraping, and when I soup it, the variable becomes blank.

```html
<!-- example.html -->

<html><head><title>The Website Title</title></head>
<body>
<p>Download my <strong>Python</strong> book from <a href="http://
inventwithpython.com">my website</a>.</p>
<p class="slogan">Learn Python the easy way!</p>
<p>By <span id="author">Al Sweigart</span></p>
</body></html>
```

```py
import bs4
example = open('example.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(example.read())
print(soup) # returns '[]'
```

Comment: Could you clarify if `example =`  line is something like `example = open('example.html')` ?

Comment: Okay then, I will.

Comment: If that's your complete code - then it should work just fine... Are you sure `soup` is actually `[]` as `BeautifulSoup` returns `None` if there's nothing to parse or a Soup object... it'll never return what you say it is... have you somehow assigned something later on or otherwise got old variables hanging around and not using the ones you think you are?

Comment: I ran your code and it is showing output on my system.

Comment: Huh... I was doing it on IDLE, so I'll try with an actual file.

Comment: I have tried it with IDLE again and I have seemed to have used one backwards slash instead of 2. This has changed the output for me.